# How to show label name of a data in y-axis in recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

**Problem:**

I have created a vertical bar charts using recharts. Here I am providing my code.

```js
import React, { Component, PureComponent } from "react";

import { Card, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";
import {
  Bar,
  BarChart,
  Tooltip,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Cell,
  LabelList
} from "recharts";

import "./SubcribersByRegion.css";

const colors = [
  "#138185",
  "#26a0a7",
  "#65d3da",
  "#79d69f",
  "#cbe989",
  "#ebf898",
  "#f9ec86",
  "#fad144",
  "#ec983d",
  "#d76c6c"
];

const data = [
  {
    name: "Page A",
    pv: 2400,
    amt: 2400
  },
  {
    name: "Page B",
    pv: 1398,
    amt: 2210
  },
  {
    name: "Page C",
    pv: 9800,
    amt: 2290
  },
  {
    name: "Page D",
    pv: 3908,
    amt: 2000
  },
  {
    name: "Page E",
    pv: 4800,
    amt: 2181
  },
  {
    name: "Page F",
    pv: 3800,
    amt: 2500
  },
  {
    name: "Page G",
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  },
  {
    name: "Page H",
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  },
  {
    name: "Page I",
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  },
  {
    name: "Page J",
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  }
];

class SubcribersByRegion extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card className="subscribers-by-region-card">
          <CardTitle className="subscribers-by-region-card-title">
            Subscribers by Region
          </CardTitle>
          <CardBody>
            <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%" aspect={5.0 / 6.0}>
              <BarChart
                data={data}
                layout="vertical"
                barGap={4}
                margin={{
                  top: 6,
                  right: 50,
                  left: 0,
                  bottom: 0
                }}
              >
                <Tooltip />
                <XAxis type="number" className="xaxies" dy={1} />
                <YAxis type="category" />
                <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8" maxBarSize={10}>
                  {data.map((entry, index) => (
                    <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={colors[index]} />
                  ))}
                  <LabelList dataKey="pv" position="right" />
                </Bar>
              </BarChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SubcribersByRegion;
```

This is showing me 0,1,2....... in the y-axis I want to show Page A, Page B,...
Can someone help me to solve this issue by modifying my code? Thank you? I tried a lot to find a solution to this problem but I was unable to find any good solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to specify what the `dataKey` is for the axis.

`<YAxis type="category" dataKey="name" />`

Answer (score 4):

https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis

From the docs, we can see `<Label />` is a child component of `YAxis`

https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Label

`Label` has a prop for `value`

Add the `Label` Component as a child of `YAxis`

Add styles https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/720

```
<YAxis dataKey={"height"} yAxisId={"height"}>
    <Label
         style={{
             textAnchor: "middle",
             fontSize: "130%",
             fill: "white",
         }}
      angle={270} 
      value={"Height (ft.)"} />
</YAxis>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XAxis and YAxis do have a property named as label which can be used to provide the label text in the axes.
A sample example 
This is an optional one so if you are looking for an answer in 2023, maybe this can be helpful. For the same, the below can be referred from the official documentation https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis